# Custom trigger type in Experience optimization

Tags: dxa, experience-optimization, dxa2.2

I have a DXA 2.2 web app set up along with the XO module. Promotions created in the "CME targeting section" are working fine when I am using OOTB trigger types (like browser type etc.).

Now I am trying to create a custom trigger type, a very simple boolean based trigger type. I was thinking that it may be possible to write custom trigger types without writing any cartridge. With that understanding I wrote some code in httpmodule and code is pretty simple and looks like:

```
        Uri uri = new Uri("taf:claim:demo:showpromotion");
        if (!AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore.Contains(uri))
        {
            AmbientDataContext.CurrentClaimStore.Put(uri, true, ClaimValueScope.Session);
        }
```

This code is adding a claim to the claim store. I configured samrttergetconf and ambiend_data_conf in the application along with microservices (Session enabled content service) so that this claim is forwarded. Corresponding files form my web app are shown below:

[image]

[image]

But in the smart target Model builder, in its ExecuteSmartTargetQuery method, my custom trigger is not returned from the AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers(ClaimStore) method call.

I have not written any cartridge and I am trying to set the claims from my dotnet application only. So my questions are:

1. Is it possible to use custom triggers without writing any cartridge for them? or writing a cartridge is mandatory?
2. If it should work without a cartridge, then what am I missing, and why my custom trigger is not returned from the AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers method call?

Comment: Did you create the New Xo Trigger Type correctly? Did you configure the xo session cartridge extension?  Answer to your question, Yes it's possible, not mandatory. double-check the xo-promotions triggers in elastic http://localhost:9200/xo-promotions/_search?size=1000 and also double check the xo trigger type in elastic http://localhost:9200/xo-triggertypes/_search?size=1000

Comment: AmbientFrameworkModule is mandatory in the web.config.

Comment: Which version of SDL Tridion sites? Did you use an add-on service?

Answer (score 0):

In order to further troubleshoot copy, this **QueryBuilder.aspx** page to your DXA website root folder and change the values according to your environment and try to validate against your trigger types and regions check the response.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.SmartTarget.Query.Builder" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.SmartTarget.Analytics" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.SmartTarget.Query" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.SmartTarget.Utils" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Tridion.ContentDelivery.AmbientData" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Newtonsoft.Json" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Newtonsoft.Json.Converters" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Collections.Generic" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Diagnostics" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void Execute(QueryBuilder queryBuilder)
    {
        var resultSet = queryBuilder.Execute();
        var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            Converters = { new StringEnumConverter() }
        };
        
        Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        Response.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(resultSet, jsonSettings));
    }
    
    protected void AddTriggers(QueryBuilder queryBuilder)
    {
        var triggers = AmbientDataHelper.GetTriggers();
        foreach(var kvp in triggers)
        {
            queryBuilder.AddCriteria(new CustomParameterCriteria(kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
        }
    }
    
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] regions = new[] { "Sidebar", "Header" };
        TcmUri _pageUri = new TcmUri("tcm:7-61-64");
        TcmUri _publicationUri = new TcmUri(0, _pageUri.PublicationId, 1);

        var queryBuilder = new QueryBuilder(_publicationUri, regions);
        AddTriggers(queryBuilder);

        Execute(queryBuilder);
    }
</script>
```

I hope it helps.